# Disable HTML reporting for TestNG with Maven

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

We run TestNG tests with Maven 3.0.5, Surefire 2.7.1, and TestNG 5.10.

We want to disable generation of HTML reports that are create under `target/surefire-reports/Command line suite`, the latter directory being a TestNG suite name. We believe that it's TestNG's reporter that creates a report, but despite the following configuration, the reporting cannot be disabled.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is there a way to switch off the HTML reporting? It takes a painful amount of time on each test run.

Comment: Can you try upgrading TestNG to 5.14.9 or newer (like 5.14.10 or 6.8 which is the latest)? Alternatively, upgrade to version  2.19.1 of Surefire Plugin.

Comment: I have tried it with TestNG 5.14.10 and Surefire 2.19.1 both upgraded in the same run, it did not help.

Comment: Hmm I just tried with TestNG 6.9.8 and 5.14.10 with Surefire 2.19.1 and the configuration in your post worked, as in, no HTML report was created. Are you sure this configuration isn't in a `<pluginManagement>` section?

Comment: It worked finally. It appeared I did not configure the versions properly the first time. Thanks a lot! Will you put your solution as an answer, so that it will be documented properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug with those versions of TestNG and Surefire, making configuring with the listeners not working. From [Using Custom Listeners and Reporters](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#Using_Custom_Listeners_and_Reporters) in the Surefire documentation:

> Unsupported versions: - TestNG 5.14.1 and 5.14.2: Due to an internal TestNG issue, listeners and reporters are not working with TestNG. Please upgrade TestNG to version 5.14.9 or higher. Note: It may be fixed in a future surefire version.

This probably affect 5.10 as well, so you need to upgrade to a newer version of TestNG. While at it, you can also upgrade Maven Surefire Plugin to the current latest, which is 2.19.1:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.9.8</version> <!-- or 5.14.10 for the latest in 5.x branch -->
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
        <value>false</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is it worth adding that this will disable the HTML reports from being generated by TestNG, but Surefire itself will still generate an XML report. You can disable that one with the [`disableXmlReport`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#disableXmlReport) parameter in the Surefire configuration.